# Compress time into day-format and count based on other column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have some data with a sentiment classification (1 or -1), I would like to get a daily sum of the count of each of them. For example:

```
time2                   sent_reclass
2015-01-12 21:43:00             1
2015-01-12 10:43:00             -1
2015-01-12 4:43:00              -1
2015-01-13 21:43:00             1
2015-01-13 12:43:00             1
2015-01-13 09:43:00             -1
```

into

```
date                    dailyCountPos1      dailyCountNeg1
2015-01-12                      1                   2
2015-01-13                      2                   1
```

But I don't know how to compress the time into day-format while counting the frequency of +1 and -1 at the same time. My following code only gives the toal count instead of daily count, and I also know how to compress time into day-format (ie: count = s.dt.date.value_counts()) separately but not together.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get data in df
data = pd.read_csv('someFile.csv', header=0, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df = DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort(['time'], ascending=True)  # Sort by time

# Create a new pandas column within df based on time
df['time2'] = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(date) for date in df['time'])

# Use groupby to count number of occurence by sent_reclass and add as a new pandas col
df['sent_count'] = df.groupby(['sent_reclass'])['time2'].transform('count')

print df.head()

        sent_reclass           city stateScan               time2 sent_count  
567                 1        Atlanta      True 2015-01-12 21:43:00      29034  
566                 -1        Detroit      True 2015-01-12 21:43:00      21561  
565                 -1        Fishers      True 2015-01-12 21:43:00      21561  
564                 1  Coeur d'Alene      True 2015-01-12 21:43:00      29034  
563                 -1            NaN      True 2015-01-12 21:43:00      21561
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your dates, you can just split it (by space by default) and take the first element, and omit the time. You don't even have to use datetime etc.

And for counting, you can use defaultdict combined with Counter:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

date_counts = defaultdict(Counter)

date_counts['2015-01-12'].update({'pos': 1})
date_counts['2015-01-12'].update({'neg': -1})
date_counts['2015-01-12'].update({'neg': -1})
date_counts['2015-01-13'].update({'pos': 1})
date_counts['2015-01-13'].update({'pos': 1})
date_counts['2015-01-13'].update({'neg': -1})

print dates_counts

defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'2015-01-12': Counter({'pos': 1, 'neg': -2}), '2015-01-13': Counter({'pos': 2, 'neg': -1})})
```

I hope this helps ;-)

EDIT:

```
for datetime_string, num in df['<date_column>', '<num_column>']:
    date = datetime_string.split()[0]
    d = dict(pos=num) if num > 0 else dict(neg=num)
    date_counts[date].update(d)
```

Comment: Thanks although it works for the above example, my data's dates don't restrict to only two dates, it has tens of thousands of dates, hence I want to add the count columns into the original pandas df. And at the end I want to create a time series graph based on the count, so using datetime is necessary.

Comment: I know, but sometimes pandas, scipy and numpy are not the solution to everything, Python's stdlib and easy tricks can often do the job better and faster. I say that because I notice that more and more new python devs immediately jump to these 3 libraries and do not try to leverage the stdlib like old coders like me ;-)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't need pandas if other modules can do what I need to do. If I understand your answer correctly you are suggesting to hard code date_counts['2015-01-13'] and date_counts['2015-01-12'] and find the count, I am indicating it is impossible to hard code all the dates like this since I have tens of thousands of different dates.

Comment: Of course not hardcoding, it was to show you how to use defaultdict(Counter). Imagine this in a for loop where the date part of the initial datetime string would come as a variable and a simple if/else to check if the number is positive or negative. Defaultdict will only create the date key if it is not already present, and Counter will sum up you "pos: or "neg" values automatically ;-)

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: I did an edit to my post, I believe this is the way pandas can give you only 2 colums values and a list of lists. But my answer was more to show you defaultdict and Counter. collections.* are really powerful tools, most people don't use them but should.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) and [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""time2;sent_reclass
2015-01-12 21:43:00;1
2015-01-12 10:43:00;-1
2015-01-12 4:43:00;-1
2015-01-13 21:43:00;1
2015-01-13 12:43:00;1
2015-01-13 09:43:00;-1"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None, parse_dates=[0])
print df
                time2  sent_reclass
0 2015-01-12 21:43:00             1
1 2015-01-12 10:43:00            -1
2 2015-01-12 04:43:00            -1
3 2015-01-13 21:43:00             1
4 2015-01-13 12:43:00             1
5 2015-01-13 09:43:00            -1
```

```
#remove time from column time2
df['time2'] = df['time2'].dt.normalize()
print df
       time2  sent_reclass
0 2015-01-12             1
1 2015-01-12            -1
2 2015-01-12            -1
3 2015-01-13             1
4 2015-01-13             1
5 2015-01-13            -1

#pivot table and count
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='time2', columns='sent_reclass', aggfunc=len)
print df
sent_reclass  -1   1
time2               
2015-01-12     2   1
2015-01-13     1   2

#if you need set column names
df.columns = ['dailyCountNeg1','dailyCountPos1']
print df.reset_index()
       time2  dailyCountNeg1  dailyCountPos1
0 2015-01-12               2               1
1 2015-01-13               1               2
```